# How to disable iOS default glossy effect on my custom button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I use the `resizableImageWithCapInsets` method to create a custom button from this image:

[image: gradient image]

The problem is I cannot manage to disable the following effect which makes a clear horizontal limit appear in the middle of the button:

[image: button rendered by iOS]

Where does it come from and how can I disable it ?

Here is the code for information:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeButton.png"]
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
[saveButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Comment: AFAIK There is no such default gloss. Try another image (one where stretching issues would be obvious) and see. I think your insets could be wrong.

Comment: @David you are right, the insets were wrong (they were adapted to the standard image while I was using the retina version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tried in preview... and it is the effect you get when you cut the image the way you do. you got HUGE insets, so you get 18 pixels for l/r/t/b ..

to do what you want maybe use way smaller insets: e.g. 5,5,5,5 or so

Comment: The insets were wrong indeed. (actually the image size was wrong, I replaced the 72x72 image by a 36x36 image and things went back to order).